# How to read multiple record from xml to insert in table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xml

```
DECLARE @tbl_XMLResult table
(
    Status varchar(50),
    Address varchar(100),
    ListPrice varchar(25),
    SoldPrice varchar(25),
    YearBuilt varchar(25),
    SF varchar(25),
    Acres varchar(25),
    OnMarkDate varchar(25),
    PendDate varchar(25),
    SaleDate varchar(25),
    DOM varchar(25)
)

DECLARE @XMLRESULT xml

exec usp_ReportResults @query = "759,905,1048,170,725,80129", @ReportName = "GenReport", @XMLResult = @XMLRESULT OUTPUT

INSERT INTO @tbl_XMLResult(Status, Address, ListPrice, SoldPrice,
        YearBuilt, SF, Acres, OnMarkDate, PendDate, SaleDate, DOM)
    SELECT
        Listing.value('(/ListingStatus/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Status, 
        ReportData.value('(/Listing_StreetAddress/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Address,
        Listing.value('(/ListPrice/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ListPrice,
        Listing.value('(/ClosePrice/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')AS SoldPrice,
        Listing.value('(/YearBuilt/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS YearBuilt,
        Listing.value('(/TotalLvSpace/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS SF,
        Listing.value('(/AcresApx/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Acres,
        Listing.value('(/ListDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') OnMarkDate,
        Listing.value('(/PendingDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS PendDate,
        Listing.value('(/CloseDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS SaleDate,
        Listing.value('(/DaysOnMarket/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') DOM
    FROM 
        @XMLRESULT.nodes('/Results/Report/Listings/Listing') AS ListingTable(Listing),
        @XMLRESULT.nodes('/Results/Report/Listings/Listing/PMCReportData') AS TempTable(ReportData)

SELECT *
FROM @tbl_XMLResult
```

I am trying to get result from stored procedure as in xml format and by reading that result store it into the temporary table created above. But I'm getting result as `null` and current stored procedure returning only six records in xml but it showing 36 rows in temporary table with `null` values in it. How to fix that?

This is the xml format:

[image: xml format]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to remove the `/` at the start of the `value()` function. i.e. this one `Listing.value('(/`.
2. You also need to remove the `CROSS JOIN` that occurs because you are using old style `JOIN` syntax between `ListingTable(Listing)` and `TempTable(ReportData)`. You can do that by referencing the PCMReportData slightly differently.

Based on your XML schema, you should then get values e.g.

```
DECLARE @XMLRESULT XML;

SET @XMLRESULT = '<Results ReplyCode="0" ReplyText="Operation Successfull">
                    <Report PropertyType="ResidentialProperty">
                    <Listings>
                    <Listing>
                      <ListingID>759</ListingID>
                      <PCMReportData>
                        <Listing_StreetAddress>My Street Address</Listing_StreetAddress>
                      </PCMReportData>
                    </Listing>
                    <Listing>
                      <ListingID>852</ListingID>
                    </Listing>
                    </Listings>
                    </Report>
                    </Results>';

SELECT 
  Listing.value('(ListingID/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ListingID,
  Listing.value('(PCMReportData/Listing_StreetAddress/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Address
FROM @XMLRESULT.nodes('/Results/Report/Listings/Listing') AS ListingTable(Listing);
```

You're doing a `CROSS JOIN` between `ListingTable(Listing)` and `TempTable(ReportData)`. Therefore the 6 results, multiplied by the 6 inner results = 36.